# Error configuring Kerberos on CentOS 6

Tags: security, hadoop, kerberos, centos6

After configuring Kerberos on private server which runs on CentOS 6, I get this error when I run the `kinit` I get the following response:

> kinit: Realm not local to KDC while getting initial credentials

This is the copy of my config file:

```html
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = true
 dns_lookup_kdc = true
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
# rdns = false
 default_realm = CENTSERVER01
# default_ccache_name = KEYSTRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
 CENTSERVER01 = {
  kdc = centserver01:88
  admin_server = centserver01:88
 }

[domain_realm]
 .centserver01 = CENTSERVER01
 centserver01 = CENTSERVER01
```

Comment: Could you share your kerberos configuration: /etc/krb5.conf /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.conf

Comment: Thanks @T-Heron, you have answered my question. But the still experiencing the error.

Comment: Well, I don't actually consider it to be an answer if there's still a problem.  What have you changed since Jan 12th, and what is the current error message you're getting?  Can you edit your question with these details?

Answer (score -1):

This error usually means that your Kerberos configuration file, which is by default /etc/krb5.conf, is configured wrong.  You'll need to fix that, in order to fix the problem.  These errors are usually caught through a simple visual examination of this file.  Edit the file according to the [sample krb5.conf file on the MIT web site](http://web.mit.edu/KERBEROS/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5.4/doc/krb5-admin/Sample-krb5_002econf-File.html); simply replace the the example.com name with your actual Kerberos realm name and DNS name, keeping note of case sensitivity throughout.